# Datatables: Count rows with specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, css-selectors, datatables-1.10

I have a table with various columns and many rows. To simplify this, I just need to know how many rows are billable (in this case, column 2). In other words, how many rows in column 2 have the text "y"? Anyways, this is what I've tried so far:

**jQuery**

```
var billable = 0;

// attempt 1
table.rows().eq(1)( function () {
    if(table.data() === 'y'){
       //priceTotal+=parseInt(table.cell(row,0).data());
        alert('This is the billable column, now count which equal "y".')
        billable++;
    }
});  

// attempt 2
column(2).data() === "y"){
    alert('This is the billable column, now count which equal "y".')
    billable++;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s827x/3/

Comment: have you considered using angularjs?

Answer (score 2):

with jquery we can select element by the index in the parent Element: [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), so simply:

```
$( ".our-table td:nth-child(2):contains('y')" ).length;
```

Just added to HTML (just in case):

```
<tbody class="our-table">
```

and using the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) Selector, we selecting all the `<td>` in column 2, that `:contains('y')`

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s827x/6/**

Comment: This works nicely for currently shown rows, but doesn't count the entire datatable. I have 197 rows.

Comment: @triplethreat77, can you please Give an example of your large table?, I tried with a large table and it seems to work.
http://jsbin.com/porosoyu/1/edit

Comment: also, datatables removes / injects <tr>'s / <td>'s when it filter rows / show/hide columns, so you could easily get a wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

Use the dataTables API to cycle through all the rows :

```js
var rowCount = table.rows()[0].length;
for (var row=0;row<rowCount;row++) {
    if (table.cells(row, 1).data().indexOf('y')>-1) {
        billable++;
    }
}
alert(billable+' total');
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/3C9Rk/**

Note : `Cells` is zerobased, and the number of rows can be found multiple ways, the above is just an API example.

Answer (score 0):

isherwood's example would work for an exact match, but this would also work if you're only looking for matches that *contain* a search term:

```
function countContaining(table, search) {
  var count = 0;
  $(table).find('td').each(function(e) {
    if (e.innerHTML.indexOf(search) > 0) {
      count++;
    }
  });
  return count;
}
```

Comment: `table` is a datatables API object, not a jQuery object.